# Drawing circle/ellipse on HTML5 canvas using mouse events

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want something like ellipse option in paint for drawing on my canvas. I have achieved this partially. The problem is I am not able to get radius of circle; currently I have hard coded it to 15. Also I want to draw an ellipse (like in paint) not exact circle.

This is my code for drawing circle on canvas using mouse events. Please help me with code to achieve my above mentioned requirements.

```js
function tool_circle() {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        tool.started = true;
        tool.x0 = ev._x;
        tool.y0 = ev._y;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
        if (!tool.started) {
            return;
        }

        context.fillStyle = 'red';

        var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tool.x0 - ev._x, 2) + Math.pow(tool.y0 - ev._y));
        context.beginPath();
    
        context.arc(tool.x0, tool.y0,15, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started) {
            tool.mousemove(ev);
            tool.started = false;
            img_update();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I would something similar as with markE's answer however, using Bezier curve will draw ellipses but it won't give you the exact radius that you probably would need.

For that a function to draw a manual ellipse is needed, and it's rather simple -

This function will take a corner start point and and end point and draw an ellipse **exactly** within that boundary:

## [Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/svszcu5f/2/)

[image: Snapshot from demo]

```
function drawEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var radiusX = (x2 - x1) * 0.5,   /// radius for x based on input
        radiusY = (y2 - y1) * 0.5,   /// radius for y based on input
        centerX = x1 + radiusX,      /// calc center
        centerY = y1 + radiusY,
        step = 0.01,                 /// resolution of ellipse
        a = step,                    /// counter
        pi2 = Math.PI * 2 - step;    /// end angle
    
    /// start a new path
    ctx.beginPath();

    /// set start point at angle 0
    ctx.moveTo(centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(0),
               centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(0));

    /// create the ellipse    
    for(; a < pi2; a += step) {
        ctx.lineTo(centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(a),
                   centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(a));
    }
    
    /// close it and stroke it for demo
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

The demo marks the rectangle area too to show that the ellipse is exactly within it.

## Draw

To handle mouse operation that will let you draw the ellipse you can do:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    x1,                 /// start points
    y1,
    isDown = false;     /// if mouse button is down

/// handle mouse down    
canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {

    /// get corrected mouse position and store as first point
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    x1 = e.clientX - rect.left;
    y1 = e.clientY - rect.top;
    isDown = true;
}

/// clear isDown flag to stop drawing
canvas.onmouseup = function() {
    isDown = false;
}

/// draw ellipse from start point
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

    if (!isDown) return;
    
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x2 = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y2 = e.clientY - rect.top;
    
    /// clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    /// draw ellipse
    drawEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

A tip can be to create a top canvas on top of your main canvas and do the drawing itself there. When mouse button is released then transfer the drawing to your main canvas. This way you don't have to redraw everything when drawing a new shape.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I saw the demo, it is nice. But, it is allowing us to draw only one circle. Can I be able to draw as many circles as I want on the canvas?

Comment: @user130004 of course, just add a canvas on top which you use to drag and draw. When mouseup draw that canvas back to the main canvas on top of what's already there. If you want to redraw everything you can store the circle data in an array (center x,t and radius) and redraw from that.

Comment: @user130004 here´s a modification of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/37vge/21/

Comment: i am trying to erase the certain part of circles drawn. For that I wrote the following code. Please check it and tell where I am going wrong. Sorry, if my code is too bad... (http://jsfiddle.net/saipavan579/sqwt2cqp/)

Comment: Hi @KenFyrstenberg, I want to do the same thing for a mobile app (Phonegap wrapped) on touch events. I tried your code (i tried markE's code also), just by replacing onmousedown,onmousemove with ontouchstart,ontouchmove events. These events are getting triggered as I can see the logs, but its not drawing the ellipse/circle. Anything special I need to do for touch events? Thanks in advance (I am using Canvas for the first time :) )

Comment: How can i add fill color in it ?

Comment: Hello @K3N any ideas on how we add rotation into the oval based on start and end points? Thanks

Comment: @NickyWaites it's possible to do using either the builtin transformation matrix (context.rotate) combined with translate to rotate around center, or use a custom matrix to convert each point that is calculated. I made a polyfill a while back, published it now as gist: https://gist.github.com/epistemex/80e929635faa7b522a49aa2fd84d08de This will have the math etc. to do rotation, start and end point etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how to drag-draw an oval.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3SFJy/

[image]

Example code using 2 Bezier curves to drag-draw an oval:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:0px;}
#canvas{ border:1px solid blue; }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;

    function drawOval(x,y){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX, startY + (y-startY)/2);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX, startY, x, startY, x, startY + (y-startY)/2);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, y, startX, y, startX, startY + (y-startY)/2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      if(!isDown){ return; }
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      if(!isDown){ return; }
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(!isDown){ return; }
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      drawOval(mouseX,mouseY);
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Drag to create a circle or oval</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @markE, I want to do the same thing for a mobile app (Phonegap wrapped) on touch events. I tried your code, just by replacing mouseup,mousemove with touchstart,touchmove events. These events are getting triggered as I can see the logs, but its not drawing the ellipse/circle. Anything special I need to do for touch events? Thanks in advance (I am using Canvas for the first time :) )

Answer (score 2):

Here's my way of drawing an ellipse onto a canvas with mouse drag.

It uses radius of 1, but dynamic scaling to get the ellipse effect :)

https://jsfiddle.net/richardcwc/wdf9cocz/

```js
//Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables
var scribble_canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
var scribble_canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
var scribble_last_mousex = scribble_last_mousey = 0;
var scribble_mousex = scribble_mousey = 0;
var scribble_mousedown = false;

//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    scribble_last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-scribble_canvasx);
 scribble_last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-scribble_canvasy);
    scribble_mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    scribble_mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    scribble_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-scribble_canvasx);
 scribble_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-scribble_canvasy);
    if(scribble_mousedown) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //clear canvas
        //Save
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        //Dynamic scaling
        var scalex = 1*((scribble_mousex-scribble_last_mousex)/2);
        var scaley = 1*((scribble_mousey-scribble_last_mousey)/2);
        ctx.scale(scalex,scaley);
        //Create ellipse
        var centerx = (scribble_last_mousex/scalex)+1;
        var centery = (scribble_last_mousey/scaley)+1;
        ctx.arc(centerx, centery, 1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        //Restore and draw
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    //Output
    $('#output').html('current: '+scribble_mousex+', '+scribble_mousey+'<br/>last: '+scribble_last_mousex+', '+scribble_last_mousey+'<br/>mousedown: '+scribble_mousedown);
});
```

```css
canvas {
    cursor: crosshair;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<div id="output"></div>
```