# Drawing tool selection on key press in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a javascript canvas drawing program and I want the user to be able to choose between the pencil tool, circle tool and clearing screen on keypress.

In the following code the variable key_press holds the users selection. The whole program does not work when I don't assign anything to the variable, so I made the default value = pencil(). But now I cant use anything but pencil. 
I post only relevant code here, but it is full in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WzU2d/)

```
      var canvas, context, tool, key_press;

      // check for key press
    window.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
           key_press= String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);         
       },false);

    function init () {
      canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                //check user selection
            if (key_press === "1") {
                tool = new Pencil();
            } else if (key_press === "2") {
                tool = new Circle();
            } else if (key_press === "3") {
                canvas.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);  
                tool = new Pencil();
            } else tool = new Pencil();  //this part is probably causing the problem, but clear screen (selection 3) does not work either so it could be something different.

         //onmouse calls and end of init()
    }

    //basically just two functions after init for the tools

    function Pencil () {
    //...
    }

    function Circle() {
    //...
    }

    //calling main function init()
    init();
```

Obviously the way I handle user input is bad. Could you point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: asks people to do his work for him..

Comment: Its pretty much finished, but I cant figure out how to do the button functions and why doesnt the circle draw.

Comment: @user So, why don't you give us a jsfiddle, post the _relevant code only_, describe the problem, attempt a solution (and post that), and tell us why it didn't work?

Comment: @bjb568 Upvoted because this is the user's first post, it's not really that bad (especially compared to what we usually get) and also I thought you were being rude. Basically to offset your downvote. Here is a fiddle, I can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/na2A4/ However it seems that this *is* the "relevant code only".

Comment: Maybe because I just had to google jsfiddle... And I posted my solution because I dont know why it didnt work...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594756/drawing-circle-ellipse-on-html5-canvas-using-mouse-events

Comment: @Wesley My downvote didn't affect rep. You just got the user 5 rep, giving _more power_. You don't want to give an untrusted user like this more power.

Comment: @bjb568 Power to do what, exactly? Get real.

Comment: @Wesley Murch Ok so I edited the code and it almost works now, but it does not seem to run in jsfiddle for some reason... http://jsfiddle.net/rWV5h/
I figured out the circle with that ellipse link, now I want to figure out how to use keys as tool slectors... I tried it with keydown event listener on line 13 (in comment tags), but that didnt work for me :/

Comment: Can you post also the error messages that you get? . . . PS: I voted to reopen but now I'm not sure if you made a *completely new question* (not good because invalidates the answer already provided) or simply improved the original (deserving reopening and other answers).

Comment: Ok I edited it even further, because I made some changes and now Im not getting any errors. This was part of my original question, but it did not get answered, because I had other, bigger problems within the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your distance calculation wasn't working because you left off a `, 2` in the second `Math.pow` call.
Your jsfiddle wasn't working because the default on a new fiddle is to run in `window.load`, but you then added another load event listener that never fired.

I've changed the code to reflect these changes (and make the `context.arc` call use the distance rather than `z`) and it appears to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/rWV5h/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for that it helped a lot. I cleared up a lot of things yesterday, but need help just with that one last piece- selecting the tool. I edited the post to remove all the information thats not useful anymore.