# Issue with oval thicker border stroke at curve point

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs here i have an option CUSTOM DECAL to draw shape on on canvas.I am getting issue with the oval shape when i stroke or increase the border width of OVAL shape at the curve point of OVAL shape it's showing border width double compare than up and bottom side of OVAL.

Code sample i have used to stroke oval border

```
//*****************scale oval canvas border width*******************

var ovalstrokewidth=0;
$("#ovalstrokewidth").change(function() {
var otrokew=(this.value);
$(".width_val_oval").html(otrokew);
ovalstrokewidth= parseInt(otrokew);
ovalcval=(this.value);
var w;
var h;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
w=canvas.width / 4;
h=canvas.height / 2.4;
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(2, 1.2);
ctx.arc(w, h,ovalcrad , 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);

$("#decal_color").css('display', 'block');

//ctx.fillStyle = "#555";
ctx.fillStyle =decal_border_colour_oval;
ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
//ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
ctx.lineWidth = ovalstrokewidth;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();

};
canvas.renderAll();
});

//-----------------End scale oval canvas border width------------
```

[image: snap shot image]

[Site Link](http://cutting.bluecoresyspvtltd.com/wordpress_theme/)

1. Click on Decal Shape
2. Choose OVAL option
3. Increase border width

Comment: This may help (seem to be the basis for markE's answer too though?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594756/drawing-circle-ellipse-on-html5-canvas-using-mouse-events/21597335#21597335

Comment: I think i was getting same issue before 2 months but i didn't got the answer because there is no method still in fabricjs library files to increse oval lineWidth same for scaleX and scale of the oval border.Hence all answer's are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**The deformation of your line is due to ctx.scale(2,1.2) which also scales the linewidth.**

Instead, you can draw an ellipse using its math formula (no scaling required).

This way your lines are not deformed.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2s7pH/

```
drawEllipse(150,150,2,1.2,50);


function drawEllipse(cx,cy,ratioWidth,ratioHeight,radius){
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
    var increment=PI2/100;
    var ratio=ratioHeight/ratioWidth;

    ctx.beginPath();
    var x = cx + radius * Math.cos(0);
    var y = cy - ratio * radius * Math.sin(0);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);

    for(var radians=increment; radians<PI2; radians+=increment){ 
        var x = cx + radius * Math.cos(radians);
        var y = cy - ratio * radius * Math.sin(radians);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
     }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Is their any way to manage ctx.lineWidth  according to the X and Y origon

Comment: your answers is pretty good but after add the text on canvas Ellipse going to hide you have any idea why this happening.